# Having Isses With SQL Server Temprary Table Using PDO PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to use sql server using PDO, and  I need to use a temporary table.

I am trying following code to create table:

```
$strSQL = "Create Table #scsemData1
        (
            StudentID Varchar(14) primary key,
            EIIN Varchar(6),
            StudentName varchar(100),
            FathersName varchar(100)
        );";
try
{
    $objSTMT = $objDBConn->prepare($strSQL);
    $objSTMT->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'SQL failed:  ' . "\r\n" . 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\r\n" . 'Error Code: ' . $e->getCode();
    $objDBConn= null;
    exit("\r\n" . 'err-104');
}
```

That doesn't throw/show any error.

But when I try to delete that temporary table using code bellow:

```
$strSQL = "DROP TABLE #scsemData1";
try
{
    $objSTMT = $objDBConn->prepare($strSQL);
    $objSTMT->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "SQL failed:  <br> Error Message: " . $e->getMessage() . '<br>Error Code: ' . $e->getCode() . '<br><br>';
    $objDBConn= null;
    exit('<br>err-104');
}
```

It shows below error:

> Cannot drop the table '#scsemData1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: #Temp are visible to (and exist for) the current session.   When the session ends, the #Temp is gone

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, thanks for the reply, but sir, both code is form the same file/script and both part run at once (same time).

Comment: Actually, each call you make, the server see it as a different thread

Comment: See #Temp vs. ##Temp  (## are global)m but there are risks

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, can you explain a bit more? or how can i run multiple query on a single call? (some call need prepared statement with variable data) and also middle level call need to get the data in to variable ;(

Comment: Assuming you want to do something with the #Temp, you could expand the first call:   Create #Temp ...;Insert into #Temp ...; do more stuff;.   OR consider a stored procedure where you can pass values.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, but does pdo support mutiple query? here is what i need, create temp table, insert data to that temp table form a select query, make a select query (using join) on that temp table to get data, then delete the temp table; is all those possible in a single call using pdo?